# Nested divs getting pushed below container div whiles using PHP dynamic navigation header

Tags: php, css, html

I am developing a site using a dynamic PHP header and seem to have gotten that part working. My issues came when trying to put the remaining content in the container div along with the header div. All other content is ignored and gets pushed to the left and down below the container. I want it to be INSIDE the container and center on the page like the header does.

Here is where I am with the site:
http://maniandcompany.com/test/test/Print.php

I have tried several things including overflow:hidden; to no avail.

**Here is the HTML Page**

```
<div id="container">

<div id="header">   
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
</div>


<div id="body">

    <div class="text">
    <h1>Title H1</h1>
    <h3>H3 Copy</h3>

    <h2>H2 Title</h2>
<p>body copy p</p>

    <span class="more_pictures">more images:</span>
    </div>

<div class="main_image"><img src="images/Corporate_Id_main1.jpg" />
    </div>


    </div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

</div>
```

**Here is the CSS**

```
/*Container*/
#container {
    width:790px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

/*Body*/
#body {
    width:790px;
    margin-top:0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #484941; 
    overflow:hidden;
}

.main_image {
    float:right;
    width:527px;
    height:350px;
    margin-left:3px;
}

.text {
    float:left;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    width: 220px;
    min-height: 350px;  
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

.text h1 {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color: #666;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.text h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:12px;
    color: #F60;
}

.text h3 {
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:italic;
    color: #CCC;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}


.text p {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color: #999;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

.text .more_pictures {
    font-size:9px;
    font-style:italic;
    color: #999;
}



/*header*/
#header {
    width:790px;
    height:140px;

}

#head {
        width:790px;

}

/*logo*/
#logo {
    float:left;
    width: 260px;
    height: 100px;
}

/*main navigation*/
#nav_main {
    float:left;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: italic;
    width:240px;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:110px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;

}

#nav_main .current {
    float:left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #F60;
    text-decoration: none;


}

#nav_main .current a:link {
    color: #F60;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav_main .current a:visited, a:hover, a:active  {
    color: #F60;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#nav_main .inactive {
    padding-right: 10px;
    float:left;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#nav_main .inactive a:link{
color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav_main .inactive a:visited {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav_main .inactive a:hover, a:active {
    color: #F60;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/*NAV STYLES*/

#nav {
    float:right;
    height: 100px; /*height of our content box*/
    width: 527; /*width of our content box*/
    margin-left:3px;

}

#nav #greybox {
    height: 20px;
    width: 527px;
    background: #CCC;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-bottom:5px;

}

#nav #greybox2 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 527px;
    background: #CCC;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 60px;
}


/*Thumbstrip*/

#nav #thumbStrip {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    color: #F60;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
    height: 70px;
    width: 527px;
    margin-bottom:5px; 

}
#nav #thumbStrip .thumb {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    margin-left: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFF;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);

}
#nav #thumbStrip .thumb:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.7);
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.7);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
    transform: scale(1.7);
    transform-origin: center top;
    background: #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: visible;
    opacity:1.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;

}
#nav #thumbStrip .thumb .first {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#nav #thumbStrip .thumb p {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60%;
    color: inherit;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav #thumbStrip .thumb img {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
#nav #thumbStrip a:link, .thumbStrip a:visited {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #F60;
}
#nav #thumbStrip a:hover, #thumbStrip a:active {
    border: none;
    color: #F60;
}


/*Thumbstrip First*/

#nav #thumbStrip .thumbfirst {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    margin-left: 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFF;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);

}
#nav #thumbStrip .thumbfirst:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.7);
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.7);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
    transform: scale(1.7);
    transform-origin: center top;
    background: #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: visible;
    opacity:1.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;

}

#nav #thumbStrip .thumbfirst p {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60%;
    color: inherit;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav #thumbStrip .thumbfirst img {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

/*thumb active first*/

#nav #thumbStrip .thumbActiveFirst {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    color: #F60;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #FFF;
    opacity:1.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
#nav #thumbStrip .thumbActiveFirst:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.7);
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.7);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
    transform: scale(1.7);
    transform-origin: center top;
    background: #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: visible;
    opacity:1.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}


#nav #thumbStrip .thumbActiveFirst p {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60%;
    color: inherit;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav #thumbStrip .thumbActiveFirst img {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/*thumb active*/

#nav #thumbStrip .thumbActive {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    color: #F60;
    margin-left: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #FFF;
    opacity:1.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);


}
#nav #thumbStrip .thumbActive:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.7);
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.7);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
    transform: scale(1.7);
    transform-origin: center top;
    background: #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 3px #FFF;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: visible;
    opacity:1.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}


#nav #thumbStrip .thumbActive p {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60%;
    color: inherit;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav #thumbStrip .thumbActive img {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nav #thumbStrip a:link, #content .thumbStrip a:visited {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #F60;
}
#nav #thumbStrip a:hover, #thumbStrip a:active {
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
}

#nav #thumbStrip .thumb .first {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

**Thanks in advance for your help.**

Comment: Without knowing the contents of header.php I would say you have an extra div closing the container div inside header.php.  Make sure your not closing the container div before.

Answer (score 0):

line 119 on the source page has a div closing tag that is ending you 'body' div before your 'clear' div.

```
<div class="main_image"><img src="images/Corporate_Id_main1.jpg" />
</div>


</div>  <-- erase this closing tag.

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

</div>
```

Not to mention you have 2 sets of opening and closing head and body tags. im not sure if you're including a php file with those and then repeating them in your other pages or what, but there are a lot of stray tags on that page.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I learned that the header.php file does not need to contain all the head and doc type info. That was causing the view source to show multiple / redundant body tags & head info. I also learned that I had an extra closing Div tag in the header.php file, which was causing the page to render as closing the container. now it works!